# Loading a Model inside of a config file to pull configurations from DB and store in $config array

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm refitting an existing website to work with codeigniter. The current system stores the navigation config in a single table cell using XML in this format:

```
<NAVIGATION>
  <item1>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Home</name>
    <link></link>
    <parent>0</parent>
    <target>_self</target>
    <rel>follow</rel>
    <menu>main</menu>
  </item1>
  <item2>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Some Page</name>
    <link>some-page</link>
    <parent>0</parent>
    <target></target>
    <rel>follow</rel>
    <menu>main</menu>
  </item2>
</NAVIGATION>
```

I'm not sure what the original developer had in mind, but for reasons which will remain unexplained I would like to maintain this format for now.

I created a navigation model which pulls this XML from the db and converts it into an array.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Navigation_model extends CI_Model
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
    }

    function get_navigation()
    {
        $this->db->select('pages.block');
        $this->db->from('pages');
        $this->db->join('style','style.styleID = pages.styleID','left');
        $this->db->where('style.name','data');
        $this->db->where('pages.locID',$this->config->item('splitID'));
        $this->db->like('pages.block','<NAVIGATION>');
        $navigation_query = $this->db->get();
        $navigation_row = $navigation_query->row_array();
        return xml2array($navigation_row['block']);
    }
}

/* End of file navigation_model.php */
/* Location: ./application/model/navigation_model.php */
```

What I'm trying to do, is to load this model in a config file called navigation.php and load the navigation array into the global $config array. I tried both autoloading the model and loading inside navigation.php but to no avail.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$this->load->model('Navigation_model');
var_dump($this->Navigation_model->get_navigation());

/* End of file navigation.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/navigation.php */
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI_Config::$load
>
> Filename: config/navigation.php
>
> Line Number: 3

How can I best accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I can think in two options to accomplish this.

**1. Extend CI_Controller**

In this way, you create a class that will extend the base controller functionality, automatically load the model and provide to subclasses a way to get the menu.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    protected $navigation; 

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load_config();
    }

    protected function load_config() {
      $this->load->model('Navigation_model');
      $this->navigation = $this->Navigation_model->get_navigation();
    }
}
```

**2. Provide a helper to navigation**

With a helper, you can easily get the navigation content in all locations that you may need.

navigation_helper.php

```
function get_navigation() {
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $ci->load->model('Navigation_model');
    return $ci->Navigation_model->get_navigation(); 
}
```

And in your controller:

```
function index() {
    $this->load->helper('navigation'); //or autoload...
    $nav = get_navigation();
}
```

Comment: Interesting solutions. My problem with the first one, is that I don't need every single controller to have access to the navigation, and it seems a little odd for me to set it up that way. A navigation helper could work I suppose but I'm not sure if that's very intuitive. Would it be possible to set it up so the navigation config file pulls from the navigation model like I attempted?

Comment: I'm not sure, but comparing config and helper, I think the helper is much more intuitive.

Comment: If you don't want that every single controller have access, you can create a function e.g. `set_navigation()` in `MY_Controller` and load only in the controllers that you want.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option is to do this in your config-file config/navigation.php

```
 $CI =& get_instance();
 $CI->load->model('navigation');
 $config = $CI->navigation->get_navigation();
```

This way you will be able to acces the navigation-config like any other configuration.